# Java allowing for each thread to complete to print out in order

Tags: java, multithreading, object

I'm trying to print out in order my Log statements instead of randomly after each ping?  Should I use wait and notify from object class to allow each thread to finish? Not sure how to go about this.

Main class

```
public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException 
    {
                Scan4SMB scan4Servers = new Scan4SMB();
                List<String> networkNames = scan4Servers.doScan();

                for (String networkName : networkNames)
                    {
                        LOG.CONSOLE.debug(networkName);
                    }
    }
}
```

Scan class

```
public class Scan4SMB
{
    private final int    THREADS              = 256;
    private final int    SMB_PORT             = 445;
    private List<String>    smbNames          = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String>    foundDevicesArray   = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
    private byte[]       ip;

    Scan4Servers() throws UnknownHostException
        {
            // this code assumes IPv4 is used
            ip = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getAddress();
            LOG.CONSOLE.debug("LocalHost ip: " + ip);
        }

    Scan4Servers(Inet4Address address) throws UnknownHostException
        {
            ip = address.getAddress();
            LOG.CONSOLE.debug("LocalHost IP: " + ip);
        }

    protected List<String> doScan() throws IOException
        {
            LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Start scanning");
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
                {
                    ip[3] = (byte) i;
                    InetAddress address = null;
                    try
                        {
                            address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                        }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    executor.execute(pingRunnable(address));
                }

            LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Waiting for executor to terminate...");

            executor.shutdown();
            try
                {
                    executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
            catch (InterruptedException ignored)
                {

                }
            LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Scan finished");

            return smbNames;
        }

private Runnable pingRunnable(final InetAddress address) {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Pinging " + address + "...");
            try {

                Socket socket = new Socket(address, SMB_PORT);

                LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Connection: " + socket.toString());

                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("connected " + address.toString());

                    String ipString = address.toString().substring(1,
                            address.toString().length());
                    NbtAddress[] addr = NbtAddress
                            .getAllByAddress(ipString);

                    String NETNAME = addr[0].firstCalledName();

                    // String NETNAME1 =
                    // addr[0].nextCalledName();
                    smbNames.add(NETNAME);

                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("NETNAME " + NETNAME);

                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("addr " + addr);

                    foundDevicesArray.add(address.toString());
                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("hostname added to found "
                            + address.toString());

                    socket.close();

                }

                socket.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Not found", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // LOG.CONSOLE.debug("IO Error", e);
            }

        }
    };
}

    protected List<String> getList()
        {
            return smbNames;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe exactly how you want your output to appear? It's not clear from your question what 'in order' means.

Comment: I iterate through the ip addresses. So have it return the output in that order.

Comment: Yes, but you effectively do each ping on a separate thread via the executor service. The jobs you pass to the executor service are not guaranteed to start in any particular order. Do you want the pings to happen synchronously (i.e. sequentially), or do you want them to run in parallel?

Comment: Could `object.wait()` help in this situation in way?

Comment: Well I think the problem is that you want to run the ping jobs asynchronously (i.e. in parallel), but you want it to appear as if they are running synchronously (i.e. one after the other). What's wrong with just using one thread in your thread pool? Each job will happen sequentially then.

Comment: Only one ping was executed with one thread. How do you put the runnable in its own class and then call on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.  Here's one possible approach using a `CountDownLatch` -- a simple but versatile way to coordinate threads.  I modified your pingRunnable to accept 2 latches.  It will wait for the first latch before before printing any output.  It will clear the second latch after it's done.

This way every Runnable will wait for the previous one to be done before printing anything.  The scanning will still occur in parallel but the output will be synchronized.

Here's the modified loop in doScan method:

```
CountDownLatch lastLatch = new CountDownLatch(0);

for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++) {
    ip[3] = (byte) i;
    InetAddress address = null;
    try {
        address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CountDownLatch nextLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    executor.execute(pingRunnable(address, lastLatch, nextLatch));

    lastLatch = nextLatch;
}
```

And Here's the modified pingRunnable:

```
private Runnable pingRunnable(final InetAddress address, CountDownLatch waitFor, CountDownLatch clearWhenDone) {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                Socket socket = new Socket(address, SMB_PORT);

                waitFor.await();  // wait for all previous runners to log their output

                LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Connection: " + socket.toString());

                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("connected " + address.toString());

                    String ipString = address.toString().substring(1,
                            address.toString().length());
                    NbtAddress[] addr = NbtAddress
                            .getAllByAddress(ipString);

                    String NETNAME = addr[0].firstCalledName();

                    // String NETNAME1 =
                    // addr[0].nextCalledName();
                    smbNames.add(NETNAME);

                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("NETNAME " + NETNAME);

                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("addr " + addr);

                    foundDevicesArray.add(address.toString());
                    LOG.CONSOLE.debug("hostname added to found "
                            + address.toString());

                    socket.close();

                }

                socket.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // LOG.CONSOLE.debug("Not found", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // LOG.CONSOLE.debug("IO Error", e);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            } finally {
                clearWhenDone.countDown();  // signal to the next Runnable that we are done
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to start. I just stops after it initialize and doesn't print or return anything.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to run a bunch of tasks in parallel, (the ping), but you want the log messages to print in the order the tasks were submitted to the executor, but only after they are done.

We can do that.

```
// I'm taking some liberty with your code, so the concepts are highlighted
ExecutorService exec = ....;
// Important thing is to have a list of result futures
List<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();

// we have some way to generate our work.  For loop like above is fine.
List<String> addresses = imagineWeHaveAListOfAddresses();
for( String address : addresses ) {
  // here we record the future returned by the ExecutorService      
  results.add(exec.submit(pingRunnable(address), address);
}
// result.get() is blocking, so we'll print the addresses in the same order we submitted them.
for( Future<String> result : results ) {
   LOG.info("Finished address: " + result.get());
}
```

I hope that helps.